# How to get xpath value using python of the current instance?

Tags: python, html, xpath

I've have no idea if this is possible...  What I want to do is return the xpath value from FIREFOX when called.. using python.  Can I do this without specifying the URL?

Sorry I dont have more details and thanks for any answers you may be able to provide

Comment: I don't think you understand what xpath is.

Comment: You would be correct, I'm not real sure what it is.  Messing around with chrome I noticed each element has an xpath which I thought was a way I could access that value

Comment: Xpath is a way of accessing elements within XML/HTML trees. I still have no idea what you're asking. Providing a sample scenario and a desired behavior would help.

Comment: There is a website (login required and static URL) which contains elements that I would like to be able to access with python and use for a program (is the function of the program pertinent?)

Comment: Ah! This makes much more sense! Total XY problem. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're just looking to get your feet wet with some [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping). Basically, the idea of web scraping, is taking the html that a website returns, and parse through it for relevant information.

The subject is actually rather broad, and an entire description is out of scope, but `scrapy` is a python package that makes this relatively straightforward.

There's a tutorial here: [scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

You might also want to look at [Casperjs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) to interact with webpages in a richer way.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is what I'm looking for.  Using this method, python modules access/open websites directly for scraping, which won't work in my case (URL is to login page).  Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @user21267 If you want to programmatically interact with a webpage, login and whatnot, then you're no longer dealing with static pages. This means you need to interact with web pages in a richer way, and I would then look to Casperjs. It's worth noting that you may well need a much deeper understanding of how web pages work, specifically the role of GET and POST requests in logging in. Casperjs is the right start though.